# Split string by the first occurance from a set of delimiters with Python and regex

Tags: python, regex, split

First of all the question is tagged with `Python` and `regex` but it is not really tied to those - an answer can be high level.

At the moment I'm splitting a string with multiple delimiters with the following pattern. There are actually more delimiting patterns and they are more complex but let's keep it simple and limit them to 2 characters - `#` and `*`:

`parts = re.split('#|*', string)`

Which such approach a string `aaa#bbb*ccc#ddd` is split to 4 substrings `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`. But it is required to split either by a delimiter that occurs first in the string or by a delimiter that is most frequent in the string. `aaa#bbb*ccc#ddd` should be split to `aaa`, `bbb*ccc`, `ddd` and `aaa*bbb#ccc*ddd` should be split to `aaa`, `bbb#ccc`, `ddd`.

I know a straightforward way to achieve that - to find what delimiter occurs first or is the most frequent in a string and then split with that single delimiter. But the method has to be efficient and I'm wondering if it is possible to achieve that by a single regex expression. The question is mostly for splitting with the first occurance of the set of delimiters - for most frequent delimiter case almost for sure it will be required to calculate occurrence count in advance.

Update:

The question does not ask to split by first occurrence or most frequent delimiter simultaneously - any of this methods individually will be sufficient. I do understand that splitting by most frequent delimiter is not possible with regex without preliminary determination of the delimiter but I think there's a chance that splitting by first occurrence is possible with regex and lookahead without preparation made in advance.

Comment: No regex will find the *most frequent* pattern. You will have to rely on other language means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *it is required to split either by a delimiter that occurs first in the string or by a delimiter that is most frequent in the string.*

So you can first find all the delimiters and preserve them in a proper container with their frequency, then find the most common and first one, then split your string based on them.

Now for finding the delimiters, you need to separate them from the plain text based on a particular feature, for example if they are none word characters, and for preserving them we can use a dictionary in order to preserve the count of similar delimiters (in this case `collections.Counter()` will do the job).

Demo:

```
>>> s = "aaa#bbb*ccc#ddd*rkfh^ndjfh*dfehb*erjg-rh@fkej*rjh"
>>> delimiters = re.findall(r'\W', s)
>>> first = delimiters[0]
'#'
>>> Counter(delimiters)
Counter({'*': 5, '#': 2, '@': 1, '-': 1, '^': 1})
>>> 
>>> frequent = Counter(delimiters).most_common(1)[0][0]
'*'
>>> re.split(r'\{}|\{}'.format(first, frequent), s)
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'rkfh^ndjfh', 'dfehb', 'erjg-rh@fkej', 'rjh']
```

Note that if you are dealing with delimiters that are more than one characters you can use `re.escape()` in order to escape the special regex characters (like `*`).

Comment: The question actually asked to avoid the preliminary steps to find the first and most frequent delimiters. But if it is not possible to avoid those steps this answer gives a good implementation for them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the string.count() method to be very fast since it's implemented in C. Anything that avoids for loops will generally be faster, even if you iterate the string multiple times. This is probably the fastest solution:

```
>>> s = 'aaa*bbb#ccc*ddd'
>>> a, b = s.count('*'), s.count('#')
>>> if a == b: a, b = -s.find('*'), -s.find('#')
... 
>>> s.split('*' if a > b else '#')
['aaa', 'bbb#ccc', 'ddd']
```

Comment: .count() and .find() are faster than .split(), and if .split() is the fastest way to split.. this should easily be less than 5x the speed of optimal solution. (i'd guess less than 2x)